# Why won't Iframe load in IE11 when submit button is clicked but will in other browser types

Tags: html, iframe

So I have an Iframe line code below.

```
<iframe id="iframe" scrolling="no" src="http://m.mobilerx.net/"></iframe>
```

Where the end user enters a number and presses submit to which in the iframe it will move on to a new page. However it seems to not do that and I am forced to click on a home button located within the Iframe to load the next page.

I have tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"/>
```

Didn't work however without any extra code it operates correctly in other browsers such as Firefox and Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because IE is garbage. Chrome and Firefox are all you need in life.

Comment: I agree unfortunately this is a requirement for the project so can't avoid the fact that it needs to be done. :(

Comment: I dont see your code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the `target` attribute, and different browsers have different default targets. See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp).